# Copying a variable number of methods from one place to another in Java

Tags: java, javascript

I was wondering what would be the most efficient way of porting the following JavaScript code to Java?

```
// Copies a variable number of methods from source to target.
  rebind = function(target, source) {
  var z = 1, c = arguments.length, func;

  while (++z < c) {
    target[func = arguments[z]] = rebind(target, source, source[func]);
  }

  return target;
};

// method is a getter-setter:
// If passed with no arguments, gets the value.
// If passed with arguments, sets the value and returns target.
function rebind(target, source, func) {
  return function() {
    var value = func.apply(source, arguments);
    return value === source ? target : value;
  };
}
```

Comment: Please note, Java and JavaScript are different languages.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan Sorry!!! It was a typo - i'm aware that they are two different languages, I was wondering how I would do the same in JAVA, not javascript as the code I've pasted is obviously in javascript!

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan, I think that is precisely the question: How would you implement what's done in JavaScript here in/for Java?

Comment: Darn, people seem to beat me to the punch by seconds today. :-P

Comment: Ok, my bad. Then it makes sense to ask about it, although not very much about efficiency. It's not possible to copy methods between objects on the JVM.

Comment: @UweB Come on! get with it!

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan Okay, in that case do you mind demonstrating to me how this would be done?

Comment: @BigBug it's not possible to add new methods to an object at runtime. You could create new classes at runtime, but you can't change existing class definitions. So I can't show anything.

Comment: @BigBug It wouldn't be.

Comment: I doubt it is doable with some reasonable ammount of effort. You can iterate over class members using reflection. But copying method will require some sort of dynamic bytecode generation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't.

Java isn't dynamic like JavaScript is; you "cannot" copy methods from one place to another.

There are ways to pretend you can do it, like by implementing an object you can delegate to, by implementing an interface with static methods (JDK8+ only), scary byte-code games that break IDE functionality, run-time classloading adventures, and so on.

Except under limited, frightening circumstances, you do this all at compile or load time, too, not runtime.

Comment: +1 you can do byte code manipulation on the fly to do this, however almost any other idea you might have would be better, easier to maintain than this.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Almost?! ;) I used "frightening" deliberately--been there, done that, still have nightmares.

Comment: @BigBug There have been vendors which have provided solutions of this nature and AFAIK often they later dropped support because they found them too expensive to maintain and support.